# Remember which element had the class that was removed with removeClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, removeclass

So what I'm trying to figure out is how to remember which element had the class that was removed.

For example there are 7 rows of `<li></li>` and the 4th of it has the class "active". So now if I'm about to remove this class with jQuery `removeClass()`, how can I store this info to a variable for further use such as add back the class "active" when required?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to store the class name only or full object reference.

Comment: Store the reference in a variable....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
$(element).removeClass('active');
$(element).data('removed-class', 'active');
```

Further it can be fetched using

```
var removedClass = $(element).data('removed-class');
```

Comment: would this be more efficient than storing the index of the element?

Comment: @Huangism storing the index would be wrong in case there are multiple elements, but I think this is better because you don't need any (potentially) global variables just to remember the elements.  Just do another DOM query and you've got them.

Comment: Nice! How do you get rid of the stored "data" though? Like what if someone wants to put it in garbage collection after using it once or so? Why not just use normal variables directly instead? Variables would be gone after their lifetime/etc..

Answer (score 0):

Save the `active` element(s) in a variable when you query them:

```
var wasActive = $('li.active');
wasActive.removeClass('active');

// later...

wasActive.addClass('active');
```

Comment: I don't think it will work, as you can't use jquery on variables, can you ?

Comment: No, it works just fine. You're storing the list of objects returned by that jQuery selection. All of the jQuery operations that would apply when calling jQuery directly apply here, too.  In fact, it's more efficient (when you can) to store the reference, rather than have jQuery re-run the selection every time.